# URL to search a field for keyword on Low Search

Tags: custom-fields, url, low-search

We have a query which searches a specific custom field for a given keyword.

As an example lets assume we have a table of results, one of the columns data is a custom field called 'my_colour' which contains a colour such as red.

When we click 'red' we want to show all results from a collection where the field 'my_colour' contains 'red'.

This would give something like the following URL:

`http://example.com//results?search:my_colour=red`

Which works, but our question is, is there is a specific tag to do this for example:

`{exp:low_search:url search:my_colour='red'}`

We DONT want use filter to append the current URL, instead simply display a specific set of results for the field and keyword.

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, using the URL tag *and* GET variables for the query (not encoding it) will always use the existing query and apply the given URL tag's parameters to it. If you switch to encoded queries, you can "reset" the query by not defining a `query` parameter.

You could create the non-encoded query by hand, by composing the query string yourself:

```
http://example.com/results?search:my_colour={the_color_var}
```